# How to write at the end of each line in file through Matlab?

Tags: matlab

suppose I have matrix M like

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

and i write to file using

```
dlmwrite( fullfile('C:\Users\xyz\Documents\MATLAB','test.txt'), M, 'delimiter', ' ', 'newline', 'pc');
```

and I want to create a new file that will add a character at the end of each line like

```
1 2 3 Z

4 5 6 Z

7 8 9 Z
```

**Note: there are n number of rows and 3 cols. How to do add Z as 4th col at the end of each row.**

how can I do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first read existing data into `M`, you're going to want to use `textscan`.

```
filename = 'input.txt';

fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');
M = textscan(fid, '%d %d %d');
M = cat(2, M{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Then to write it out, you're going to want to use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) rather than `dlmwrite` because `dlmwrite` only works for numeric input arguments.

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'wb');
fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d Z\r\n', M');
fclose(fid);
```

The trick here is that `fprintf` accepts input until you run out, so rather than looping through all the rows of `M` you can simply pass the entire matrix (ensuring row-major ordering with a transpose operator) to `fprintf` and it will gladly write data to the file until it runs out of data in `M`.

Note the use of `\r\n` which is necessary for your PC line breaks.

Comment: If I already have a file with data in it with n rows and 3 cols and I want to add 4th col to each row is it possible when there is already data for 3 cols in file?

Comment: For this you would want to use `textscan` to read in the old file and then write out the new file using this approach once you have `M`.

Comment: Update your question if that is your question. Your question implies that you already have `M`.

Comment: @Leo my answer has been updated to include reading in from a file.

Comment: @Leo yes. Please try it out.

Comment: I am getting error at line fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d Z\r\n', M);

Comment: @Leo You're going to have to provide more details on the error. Also look at M and ensure that it's as you expect (N x 3)

Comment: M is (N x 3) and error is message: 'Error while evaluating UIControl Callback'
    identifier: 'MATLAB:FileIO:InvalidFid'
         stack: [0x1 struct]

Comment: You need to first close the `fid` you used to load the file (`fclose(fid)`) and then reopen it (`fid = fopen(filename, 'wb')`) prior to calling `fprintf`

Comment: yes I did that. fid = fopen('test.txt', 'rb');
M = textscan(fid, '%d %d %d');
M = cat(2, M{:});
fclose(fid);
fid = fopen('test1.txt', 'wb');
fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d Z\r\n', M);
fclose(fid);

Comment: It is possible that you're trying to write to a file that you don't have permission to write to. Put a `keyboard` command after calling `fopen` and see what the value of `fid` is. It should be non-zero.

Comment: Literally type `keyboard` after the `fopen()` command. Either that or copy/paste the commands into the command window and run them one at a time to see what is happening.

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure what you mean by that. You want to look at the value of the `fid` variable after calling `fopen()`

Comment: first time when I open file for reading value of fid is 9 and after closing and opening again for writing value of fid is -1

Comment: Yes a value of -1 means that the file cannot be opened for writing. It's likely a permissions issue.  Try the following to get the error message `[fid, errmsg] = fopen(filename, 'wb')`

Comment: fid =

    -1


errmsg =

Permission denied

Comment: @Leo As I said it is because you are unable to write to the file. Please try writing to a different file in a different location.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the help Suever. I will look into it.  Thanks Alot :)

Comment: even having your first `fid=9` shows that Matlab still has a handle on 6 other **open** files. try executing `fclose all` in the command window before you do anything else with files, then try the code in this answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `fprintf` instead:

```
A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'wt');
for i = 1:3
    fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d Z\n', A(i,1), A(i,2), A(i,3));
end
```

Comment: If I already have a file with data in it with n rows and 3 cols and I want to add 4th col to each row is it possible when there is already data for 3 cols in file?

Comment: You will have to read the data in that file and then rewrite it to a new file with the new character appended to each line.